# Windows Phone 7 - Two columns listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone

How to bind data to two columns listbox like this:

---

| Item1 | Item2 |

---

| Item3 | Item4 |

---

| Item5 | Item6 |

---

| Item7 | Item8 |

---

ItemX is button or img from datasource.

I want do it in WP7 application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want a `WrapPanel` from the Silverlight Toolkit rather than a `ListBox`. See [this link for a description](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth).

Comment: Yes, Silverlight Toolkit is what I was looking for. Thank you